# Stop Excel from Inserting ###

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

So when a column is too short in excel it will replace the values with `####`. Now if I expand the cell out I can see the dates that are in there.

I've been looking all over and can't seem to find a way to make this persistent. I save it every way I can but when I open it again the cells are back to a short size with the `####`.

Please excel gurus, enlighten me.

Comment: Are you saving these as XLSX files?  Because it should save your column sizes, and therefore not revert to the ###.  If you are working on CSV or similar text-based, non-native Excel files, they can't save the formatting so they revert to default cell sizes each time you open.

Comment: I am using CSV, that makes a lot of sense, thanks techturle

Comment: is there a way to autosize all the cells at once so I don't have to click on each one

Comment: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/microsoft-office/apply-auto-fit-property-to-multiple-columns-simultaneously/ and https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Change-the-column-width-and-row-height-72f5e3cc-994d-43e8-ae58-9774a0905f46

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are working on CSV files or other text-based, non-native Excel files, then no formatting can be saved and so the cells revert to the default width each time you open them.  To correct this, save your files as XLSX whenever possible.

You can resize all columns fairly easily by selecting them all and then resizing one column (which will cause all selected cells to match it).  A fast way to do this is to click the box in the upper-left of the sheet, just between the header for column `A` and the header for row `1`.  This will select the entire workbook.  Then double-click the dividing line between 2 columns and all selected columns will auto-size themselves.

Comment: Thanks turtle, I know it was a super noob question, thanks for the answer. I will accept it as soon as I am allowed to.